# Group Multiple CASE Expressions

Tags: sql-server, group-by, case

So I have a simple table of college student information that consists of:

- ID (PK, int, not null)
- Name (varchar(40), null)
- Age (int, null)
- Class (text, null)
- Major (text, null)

I am trying to group the students by different major classes, for example, students who are an engineering or physics major would be grouped into a larger STEM group. I had to convert the Major column to a `varchar` so the code is a bit messy but here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Calculus', 'Mechanical Engineer', 'Software Engineer', 'Web Design', 'Chemistry', 'Physics', 'Graphic Design')
            THEN 'STEM'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Pre Med', 'Neuroscience')
            THEN 'Medical'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Poly Sci', 'Pre Law', 'Visual Comminucatoins', 'Communications', 'Psycology', 'Philosophy', 'History')
            THEN 'Social Science'
        WHEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Spanish', 'English', 'Linguistics')
            THEN 'Language'
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major)
    END AS Major
FROM dbo.StudentRoster AS sr;
GROUP BY  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major);
```

Result:

```
**Major**
Undeclared
STEM
Social Science
Medical
Social Science
Undeclared
Language
Social Science
STEM
Medical
Undeclared
Language
STEM
STEM
Social Science
Undeclared
STEM
Visual Comminucatoin
Social Science
Undeclared
Undeclared
Undeclared
Social Science
STEM
Language
STEM
```

How do I group the CASE expressions so that I can get the individual counts for STEM, Medical, etc?

Comment: Or use an inner query with the `GROUP BY` in the outer query.

Comment: @PeterSmith when you say inner query, are you referring to a sub query?

Comment: @DaleBurrell Copying the exact case expression into the group by is not working. There seems to be a very inconspicuous syntax error every time I put it in there

Comment: The error is at the As of  ```END AS Major;``` of the CASE expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inner query to calculate the case expression before selecting/grouping:

```
SELECT Major, COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Calculus', 'Mechanical Engineer', 'Software Engineer', 'Web Design', 'Chemistry', 'Physics', 'Graphic Design')
            THEN 'STEM'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Pre Med', 'Neuroscience')
            THEN 'Medical'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Poly Sci', 'Pre Law', 'Visual Comminucatoins', 'Communications', 'Psycology', 'Philosophy', 'History')
            THEN 'Social Science'
        WHEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Spanish', 'English', 'Linguistics')
            THEN 'Language'
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major)
    END AS Major
  FROM dbo.StudentRoster AS sr
) AS T
GROUP BY  Major
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your question is quite straightforward. Just add the count(*) function inside the query.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Calculus', 'Mechanical Engineer', 'Software Engineer', 'Web Design', 'Chemistry', 'Physics', 'Graphic Design')
            THEN 'STEM'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Pre Med', 'Neuroscience')
            THEN 'Medical'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Poly Sci', 'Pre Law', 'Visual Comminucatoins', 'Communications', 'Psycology', 'Philosophy', 'History')
            THEN 'Social Science'
        WHEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major) IN ('Spanish', 'English', 'Linguistics')
            THEN 'Language'
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major)
    END AS Major, COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.StudentRoster AS sr
GROUP BY  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major);
```

Notice that at the end of the `CASE ... END` statement, I added the COUNT(1) function. This will provide you with the count for each Major that you have grouped by.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives you the individual counts and does not group anything together. Just a bunch of 1s in the Count column

Comment: What are you getting? I noticed an errant semi-colon, right after the `FROM dbo.StudentsRoster sr` line which I removed from the query.

Comment: STEM 1
STEM 1
Social Science 1
Language 1
STEM 1
Social Science 1
Language 1
STEM 1
Medical 1
Social Science 1
STEM 1
Social Science 1
Social Science 1
Medical 1
Social Science 1
STEM 1
Language 1
Undeclared 7
Visual Comminucatoin 1
STEM 1

Comment: When you group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sr.Major), it only groups the Undeclared majors

Comment: can you post your data? I am getting two columns, with the Major and the count for each grouped major.